# I'm trying to make the checkout working only if the client is connected but it gets me back to the login form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want my clients to proceed to checkout only if they are connected, but once I log in to an account and try to get to the checkout, I'm sent back to the login form. This is supposed to happen only when no account is connected.

Here is the cart

```
<section class="ftco-section ftco-cart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 ftco-animate">
                <div class="cart-list">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-primary">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Product name</th>
                            <th>Product size</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @if (Session::has('cart'))
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($products as $product)

                                <tr class="text-center">
                                    <td class="product-remove"><a href="{{url('/delete_from_cart/'.$product['prod_id'])}}"><span class="ion-ios-close"></span></a></td>

                                    <td class="image-prod"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(/storage/product_images/{{$product['prod_image']}});"></div></td>

                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        <h3>{{$product['prod_name']}}</h3>
                                        <p>From (Store name)</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="size">
                                        <span>{{$product['size']}}</span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="price">{{$product['prod_price']}} XAF</td>
                                    <form action="{{url('/modify_qty/'.$product['prod_id'])}}" method="POST">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        <td class="quantity">
                                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                                <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity form-control input-number" value="{{$product['qty']}}" min="1" max="2000">
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Ok">
                                        </td>
                                    </form>


                                    </td>

                                    <td class="total"><strong>{{$product['prod_price']*$product['qty']}} XAF</strong></td>
                                </tr><!-- END TR-->
                            @endforeach

                            <!-- END TR-->
                            </tbody>
                        @else

                        @endif
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
                <div class="cart-total mb-3">
                    {{-- <h3>Promo Code</h3>
                    <p>Enter a promo code if you have one</p>
                      <form action="#" class="info"> --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- <label for="">Promo code</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control text-left px-3" placeholder="Enter a promo code"> --}}
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- <p><a href="checkout.html" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">Apply </a></p> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
                <div class="cart-total mb-3">
                    <h3>Delievery informations</h3>
                    <form action="#" class="info">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Region</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-left px-3" placeholder="Enter your Region name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="country">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-left px-3" placeholder="Enter your city name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="country">Neighbourhood</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-left px-3" placeholder="Enter your neighbourhood name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="country">Street</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-left px-3" placeholder="Enter your street name">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                {{-- <p><a href="checkout.html" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">Estimate</a></p> --}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
                <div class="cart-total mb-3">
                    <p class="d-flex">
                        <span>Subtotal</span>
                        <span> {{Session::has("cart")? Session::get('cart')->totalPrice : '0'}} XAF</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="d-flex">
                        <span>Delivery</span>
                        <span>1000 XAF</span>
                    </p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="d-flex total-price">
                        <span>Total to pay</span>
                        <span> <strong>{{Session::has("cart")? Session::get('cart')->totalPrice+1000 : '0'}} XAF</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p><a href="{{url('/checkout')}}" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">Proceed to Checkout</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the controller function of the checkout

```
 public function checkout()
    {
        //Login before making payment

        if(!Session::has('client'));
        {
            return view('client.login');
        }

        if(!Session::has('cart'));
        {
            return view('client.cart');
        }


        return view('client.checkout');
    }
```

This function makes sure the client login before accessing the checkout. But the problem is even when an acount is loged in, the checkout still brings me back to login form

Comment: If it is about `client logged in`, then try to use `Auth::user()` instead of session.